# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'pages'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to add a sitemap in my nextjs app but when I visit the `http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml` page it throws this error message:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'pages'
```

[image]

pages/sitemap.xml.js file code:

```
import * as fs from "fs"
import { getDocuments } from "../firebase/firestore"

const Sitemap = () => {
  return null
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ res }) => {
  const BASE_URL = "https://www.example.com"

  const staticPaths = fs
    .readdirSync("pages")
    .filter((staticPage) => {
      return !["sitemap.xml.js", "404.js", "_app.js", "_document.js", "api"].includes(
        staticPage
      )
    })
    .map((staticPagePath) => {
      return `${BASE_URL}/${staticPagePath.replace(".js", "")}`
    })

  const collectionOne = await getDocuments("collection-one")
  const collectionTwo = await getDocuments("collection-two")

  const collectionOnePaths = collectionOne.map((singleDocument) => {
    return `${BASE_URL}/collection-one/${singleDocument.id}`
  })
  const collectionTwoPaths = collectionTwo.map((singleSolutions) => {
    return `${BASE_URL}/collection-two/${singleSolutions.id}`
  })

  const allPaths = [...staticPaths, ...collectionOnePaths, ...collectionTwoPaths]

  const sitemap = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
      ${allPaths
        .map((url) => {
          return `
            <url>
              <loc>${url}</loc>
            </url>
          `
        })
        .join("")}
    </urlset>
  `

  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
  res.write(sitemap)
  res.end()

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}

export default Sitemap
```

Anyone, please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

when you run the `npm run dev` command to start your Next.js app, the working directory is set to the **root directory of your app,** which may not contain the *pages directory*.

you can use the `process.cwd()` method to get the current working directory of your app, and then append the pages directory to the path

For example set `"page"` in `readdirSync` to `pagesDir = path.join(process.cwd(), "pages");`

```
const pagesDir = path.join(process.cwd(), "pages");

  const staticPaths = fs
    .readdirSync(pagesDir)
    .filter((staticPage) => {
      return !["sitemap.xml.js", "404.js", "_app.js", "_document.js", "api"].includes(
        staticPage
      )
    })
    .map((staticPagePath) => {
      return `${BASE_URL}/${staticPagePath.replace(".js", "")}`
    })
```

if it doesn't work try it with:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const files = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages'));
```